# How to add please select option for the month year dropdown in Jquery Date Picker?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, datepicker, monthcalendar

I have a J query date picker like below(click the link to see the image). the datepicker is showing the month and year dropdowns in this date picker.

https://cdn.toolset.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/datepicker_month_year.png?x28969

by default the date picker is showing the current year and month selected. instead of that the year and month dropdowns needs to show a "Please Select" text. if user does not select month and year, then the popup should not get closed. popup should be closed only when options are selected. what options do we need to configure for this.

```
  $('#request-dob').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: new Date,
    yearRange: "-100:+0"
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the "placeholder" attribute of input for it.
Please copy below code sample in one HTML file and see the result.

```html
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>Place Holder Sample</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-aOG0c6nPNzGk+5zjwyJaoRUgCdOrfSDhmMID2u4+OIslr0GjpLKo7Xm0Ao3xmpM4T8AmIouRkqwj1nrdVsLKEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script>
          $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '-20:+20'
            });
          } );
          </script>
        </head>
        <body> 
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Please Select"></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: its giving previous , next buttons. but i want a "Please select" text on the month and year dropdowns of jquery date picker.